# ExtJS: Using remotely loaded singleton values for store definition

Tags: javascript, extjs, parse-platform, singleton, store

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to do this (if it's even possible).

I have an app which uses parse.com to store it's data, the thing is I want each user to have a different parse.com account so their data sets don't intersect whatsoever. So I created a singleton (Settings) which stores the user's appId and apiKey, which are loaded from a general parse.com account which is managed by me and contains each user's email, appId and apiKey, so when they log into the app it gets the user's appId and apiKey.

The thing is I need to use those settings, appId and apiKey, in the definitions of my stores, as I need to send them in the headers. I've done some testing trying to set my singleton's globals when the app launchs, but at the time of the stores definition both of those "globals" are null, as the app hasn't launched yet.

Here's some of my code so I can make myself a little clearer as I know this isn't the easiest thing to understand.

Application.js

```
Ext.define('Settings', {
    singleton: true,        
    appId: null,
    apiKey: null
});


Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',        
    name: 'MyApp',        
    stores: [],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('MyApp.store.Settings').load({
            params: {
                'where': '{"email": "useremail@gmail.com"}' //email is supposed to be a user input but for the sakes of testing I just made it static
            },
            callback: function(records){
                var s = records[0];
                Settings.appId = s.get('appId');
                Settings.apiKey = s.get('apiKey');
                Parse.initialize(Settings.appId, Settings.apiKey);
            }
        });
    },


    onAppUpdate: function () {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Application Update', 'This application has an update, reload?',
            function (choice) {
                if (choice === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Things', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',        
    model: 'MyApp.model.Thing',        
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        api: {
            read: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing',
            create: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'results'
        },
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': Settings.appId, //this is null at the time of definition, but I want it to be the newly fetched value at the time of app launch
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': Settings.apiKey, //this is obviously null as well
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true
});
```

What's the way around this?

By the way.. if someone can think of a proper name for this thread please feel free to change it or suggest.

Comment: Maybe you should load your "Thing" store only after your Settings are loaded. Set autoLoad  "Thing" store to false and load it inside the callback of your "Settings" store load

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is not the loading but rather the definition of the store. As those globals are null on definition loading will use the null value. The only thing that comes to mind is defining the proxy right before that load, but setting the proxy on each store load doesn't seem as the correct way to do this.

Comment: @lascort which version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: I'm using ExtJS 6 and I haven't tried but I think the result would be the same with ExtJS 5

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Ext.define('Settings', {
    singleton: true,
    appId: null,
    apiKey: null
});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.Things', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    model: 'MyApp.model.Thing',

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        api: {
            read: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing',
            create: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'results'
        },
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        withCredentials: false,
    },
    //autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true
});

Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'MyApp',


    stores: ['Things'],
    launch: function() {
        var settings = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Settings');
        settings.on('load', function() {
            var things = Ext.getStore('Things');
            things.getProxy().setHeaders({
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': Settings.appId, 
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': Settings.apiKey, 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });
            things.load();
        });

        settings.load({
            params: {
                'where': '{"email": "useremail@gmail.com"}' //email is supposed to be a user input but for the sakes of testing I just made it static
            },
            callback: function(records) {
                var s = records[0];
                Settings.appId = s.get('appId');
                Settings.apiKey = s.get('apiKey');
                Parse.initialize(Settings.appId, Settings.apiKey);
            }
        });
    },


    onAppUpdate: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Application Update', 'This application has an update, reload?',
            function(choice) {
                if (choice === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: tried this, ends up sending the request with null values for appId and apiKey.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using routes to accomplish this, since you are using ExtJs 6. It is completely out of the box, but I thing it would be ideal for your situation. In this way you can simply be sure that when a route is called and a part of your application is loaded, you always can do some checks. This can be very useful for checking user credentials for example. [More information about routes can be found here.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/router.html) And [this is a great post](https://sencha.guru/2015/07/02/handling-user-session-with-routes/) when you want to handling user sessions through routes.

The singleton:

```
Ext.define('Settings', {
    singleton: true,        
    appId: null,
    apiKey: null
});
```

The Base store:

```
Ext.define('Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.base',
    storeId: 'base',

    autoLoad: false,

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        withCredentials: false
    },

    listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
            store.getProxy().headers = {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': Settings.appId,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': Settings.apiKey,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The Things store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Things', {
    extend: 'MyApp.store.Base',        
    alias: 'store.things',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Thing',        

    storeId: 'things',

    requires: [
        'Settings'
    ],

    proxy: {
        api: {
            read: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing',
            create: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'results'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: false, // --> set to false
    autoSync: true
});
```

Your MainController:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    requires: [
        'Settings'
    ],

    stores: [
        'Things'
    ],

    routes : {
        'user/:id' : {
            before  : 'onBeforeUser',
            action  : 'onUser'
        }
    },

    onBeforeUser : function(id, action) {
        Ext.create('MyApp.store.Settings').load({
            params: {
                'where': '{"email": "useremail@gmail.com"}' //email is supposed to be a user input but for the sakes of testing I just made it static
            },
            callback: function(records){
                var s = records[0];
                Settings.appId = s.get('appId');
                Settings.apiKey = s.get('apiKey');
                Parse.initialize(Settings.appId, Settings.apiKey);
                action.resume();
            }
        });

        // or even better

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'url/to/the/api',
            params: {
                'where': '{"email": "useremail@gmail.com"}' //email is supposed to be a user input but for the sakes of testing I just made it static
            },
            success: function(response, opts) {
                var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                Settings.appId = obj.appId;
                Settings.apiKey = obj.apiKey;
                Parse.initialize(Settings.appId, Settings.apiKey);
                action.resume();
            },
            failure: function(response, opts) {
                action.stop(true);
            }
        });
    },

    onUser : function(id) {
        Ext.getStore('things').load();
    }
});
```

Comment: interesting.. I'll give this a try and come back to you with the results, but it looks promising

Comment: It seems to fit perfectly with what you want. But I don't know the rest of your application off course. I hope it helps..

Comment: Ok, I've tried doing this but got the same result. The appId and apiKey headers were still null when loading the store. I did find a way (and I can't see how I didn't see it before) though, I posted it as an answer

Comment: I have edited my answer and tested the code. It should work with this beforeload listener in the base store, which can be used for every store to extend from

Comment: although I didn't really get to overcome my problem your solution is the closest I could get to it (with a few adjustments) so the bounty is yours

Comment: I hope you find a solution (and share it with us)!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue can be solved by moving proxy definition to constructor of 'Things' store as given below.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Things', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    model: 'MyApp.model.Thing', 
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,

    constructor: function(config) {

        config = Ext.apply({
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                api: {
                    read: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing',
                    create: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Thing'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'results'
                },
                useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
                withCredentials: false,
                headers: {
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id':  Settings.appId,
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':  Settings.appId,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        }, config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

When proxy definition is inside the constructor, Settings.appId and Settings.apiKey are resolved only at the time of instance creation of  'MyApp.store.Things'.

Comment: Looks good. The downside is that you have to implement this in every store.